# Cordova/PhoneGap working with (on demand) dynamic compilation Handlebars.js

Tags: cordova, handlebars.js, runtime-compilation

I am going to build a JavaScript/Cordova app using Handlebars.js template engine. The application build will came with precompiled templated (located in www/* folder, as usual). my boss would like to *slightly* change some templates, without having to recompile the app and publish it in the markets (Play store / Itunes ecc...).

How to archive this kind of flexibility?

When my app starts I can check for updates, download new Handlebars file and recompile them. Make sense? Can I [try to save them to file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) for avoid to download them in the future? Anyone has similar problem/scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Don't compile handlebars on mobile-devices, precompile them when packaging the app or on your servers. That's much faster!

If it possible to check for updates and download the handlebars files? Maybe, but probably not worth it unless there is a really good reason to.